# What is the best way to keep updated the info of an iOS App?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications

Since push notifications may not be delivered sometimes (you can lose a few of them), you can not run code after the iPhone is turned on to check if there is new information available from the server, and you can not run code if your iOS App is closed... **What can you do if you want to be as more accurate as possible in for example a Chat App in iOS?**

I mean, **inform the user** as faster as possible that he has new info available. Comparisons: WhatsApp is updated without any delay.

You can do background fetch if your App is in background. But if the App is closed and you miss a push, it's not going to be up to date until the next push arrives or user opens the App. The same with silent notifications. If the app is terminated by the user, you are not going to receive it. Is there any way to solve it? **It must be because other Apps do it...** If there is any "private and secret" API that they are using (I read about this answer when no one know how to do that)... Is there any way to apply to use it?

UPDATE:
I'm using push notifications. The goal is to fix when a push doesn't arrive. Example: User A send chat message to user B. User B doesn't have the App open. The system lose the push. User B is not going to receive the message until he open the App.

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications seems to be your only way even if you do loose a few of them, which I don't know how you would since they are pushed to apples secure server... but what do I know. As long as the user turns on the push notifications you should be fine. They may be delayed due to apples way of handling them. Honestly push seems to be the future, having your app constantly every minute or two check for new messages is a huge battery water in conjunction with normal texting apps. Your app should provide the best live data but since apple restricts to push notifications when the app is off or not running just stick to push notifications and only push major events to the user. I believe you can set up a job scheduler using quartz or schedulator to setup your server to push notifications to your app.

Comment: Azure Notification Hub + APNS, you would be surprised about how many push you loose and the problems that you can have...

Comment: I'm using push notifications. The goal is to fix when a push doesn't arrive. Example: User A send chat message to user B. User B doesn't have the App open. The system lose the push. User B is not going to receive the message until he open the App.

Comment: There is an online tutorial that a user made a library that checks whether the request was accepted by the server.

Comment: Can you post the link?